# Create cube in bmesh at given position in a efficient manner

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I want to create a cube in bmesh at a specific position. How can I accomplish this?

I'm interested in as efficient solution as possible btw... there will be A LOT of cubes to create every frame.

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work, could you show us what you have so far?

Comment: I've answered my own question instead - someone at blender.chat helped me with bmesh api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person going by the nick `@Random` helped me with this on blender.chat. The solution was to pass translation matrix to `create_cube` op.

`bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=0.5, matrix=mathutils.Matrix.Translation(current_point))`